# Filtrar textos sem a formatação wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, lógica

Como eu poderia filtrar somente o texto, ou seja oque estão fora das tags, os que estão nas tags html quero que permaneça, só não quero os que estão nesses tipos de tag [/et_pb_text] ou seja a estilização eu não quero, como filtrar somente o texto?  obs: estou fazendo no php, exemplo:

```
[/et_pb_text][et_pb_code admin_label=""Code"" disabled=""off""][ess_grid alias=&quot;Homepage&quot;][/et_pb_code][/et_pb_column][et_pb_column type=""1_4""][et_pb_text admin_label=""performers-title"" background_layout=""light"" text_orientation=""left"" use_border_color=""off"" border_style=""solid"" custom_margin=""||5px|"" disabled=""off""]

<h2>Based in London and working on events both across the UK and internationally</h2>
Contraband International is a high-end artist, event and entertainment agency. We supply the very best entertainers and performers for all types ofÂ <strong>corporate entertainment</strong>Â events and parties, private celebrations, PR campaigns, marketing stunts and international events. Itâ€™s our expertise, creativity and friendly approach which makes us the most sought-after talent and entertainment agency in the UK.
<h4>Performers</h4>

[/et_pb_text][et_pb_code admin_label=""Code"" disabled=""off""][ess_grid alias=&quot;Performers&quot;][/et_pb_code][/et_pb_column][et_pb_column type=""1_4""][et_pb_text admin_label=""Reality TV-title"" background_layout=""light"" text_orientation=""left"" use_border_color=""off"" border_style=""solid"" custom_margin=""||5px|"" disabled=""off"" border_color=""#ffffff""]
```

quero filtrar somente o que está legivel como o conteudo do h2, o h4, e o texto simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`wp_kses`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) pra filtrar o seu conteúdo somente com tags permitidas:

```
// remove todas as tags exceto as h2
echo wp_kses( $post->post_content, array( 'h2' => array() );
```

No link tem o formato correto do array do segundo parâmetro, que indica as tags e atributos permitidos.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo